# Does a real function constructed from a holomorphic function still satisfy the same conditions for complex theorems?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following explicit construction:

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on an open set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence in $\Omega$ such that $x_n\in \Omega \cap\mathbb{R}$ for all $n$ and $x_n\to z_0\in\Omega\cap\mathbb{R}$ (but $(x_n)_n$ not constant). Furthermore, for all $n$ we have $f(x_n) \in \mathbb{R}$.

This is all to say that $f$ is holomorphic on an open set such that $f$ is real on a convergent sequence in its domain with limit point inside the domain.

Now take $r>0$ such that the disk $D_r(z_0)$ around $z_0$ is contained in $\Omega$. I want to show that for all $x\in D_r(z_0)$ the image $f(x)$ is real.

To do this I construct $$g:\Omega\cap\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}:z\mapsto \Im(f(z)).$$
This is a real function which will still be differentiable because $f$ is holomorphic.

I now want to use the theorem for complex functions that says that if a holomorphic function vanishes for a sequence of points with limit point in its domain, then that function is identically zero. Applying this theorem to $g$ would prove that $f$ is real on the region $D_r(z_0)\cap\mathbb{R}$. But can I just apply this theorem to $g$?

Comment: Isn't the statement you are after false if we take $f$ to be the identity, and $x_n$ to be any convergent sequence of real numbers?

Comment: Im assuming you meant that you want to show $f$ is real on $D_{r} (z_0) \cap \mathbb{R}$ ? In that case, you dont have to work as hard - try proving (by induction on n) that all of f's derivatives at $z_0$ are real, that is, $f^{(n)}(z_{0}) \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, use the fact that holomorphic functions are analytic.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question. $f$ needs to be real on $(z_0-r,z_0+r)$.

Comment: My whole argument is basically saying that if $f=u+iv$, that since $v=0$ on all these points $x_n$ with limit point in $(z_0-r,z_0+r)$, then $v=0$ on all of $(z_0-r,z_0+r)$.

Comment: $g$ is real analytic on $(z_0-r,z_0+r)$ so the theorem you quoted (which applies to analytic functions in general regardless of whether they are real or complex etc) works sure; there are significant differences between real and complex analytic functions but the identity theorem is a commonality